# Does ros have rolling log files/ ability to limit total size?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ROS indigo. I am creating a custom config file for my project that helps me to control the size of the log files,and define it if should be rolling .
Is there a way to limit / control the size of default ros log that goes into .ros/log ? Or define the number of files it can generate after which it starts overwriting the first file ?

So it is more of a system maintenance question, will the logs files roll over once it crosses a certain limit or will it continue creating new logs files ?

Do  I have to write a script to take care of that ?

-Best
c-nanda

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229966/does-ros-have-rolling-log-files/-ability-to-limit-total-size-?/) by [cnanda84](https://answers.ros.org/users/25978/cnanda84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cnanda84](https://answers.ros.org/users/25978/cnanda84/) on 2016-03-29**:
Anyone has a comment? Did I explain the question well enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So it is more of a system maintenance question, will the logs files roll over once it crosses a certain limit or will it continue creating new logs files ?

See [Is it possible to control the size of log file ?](http://answers.ros.org/question/200611) for a related question. Apparently there is *some* support (`rosout.log` limited to 100MB and rolled-over at that point, but other logs will currently not (2016-04-22)). [ros/ros_comm#551](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/551) seems to extend / complete this.

I'm not entirely sure of the implications of `551`, but as [rosconsole](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole) in the end logs through `log4cxx`, it might be possible (right now, as an alternative to `551` or in combination with it) to configure `log4cxx` to use its [syslog appender](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/site/trunk/docs/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1net_1_1_syslog_appender.html). That should allow you to configure whatever tool rotates logs (such as [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)) fi, to get what you're after.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1